# Lebesgue dominated convergence counterexample

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm working on the following problem:

Given a sequence of integrable functions $f_n: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f_n \to 0$ pointwise and $|f_n(x)|≤ \frac{1}{|x|+1}$ for all $x$ and $n≥1$,
prove or find a counterexample of the following assertion: $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f_n(x)| dx=0$$

I'm thinking that this is false as the function $\frac{1}{|x|+1}$ may not dominate $|f_n(x)|$ for all $x$, but I'm not sure what sequence of $f_n$'s would serve as a counterexample here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As $$\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{|x|+1}=\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{x+1}=\infty,$$ for all $n$, there is an $a_n>n$ with
$$\int_n^{a_n}\frac{dx}{x+1}=1.$$
Let $f_n(x)$ equal $1/(x+1)$ on the interval $[n,a_n]$ and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: Where could one find a proof of the fact you cited? The existence of a subinterval $[n,a_n]$ on which the integral equals $1$? I've never seen this fact before.

Comment: if a sequence diverge to infinity for all $N_0$ there exists $N>N_0$ such that $u_N>1$. Same here with $n=N_0$ and $a_n=N$ and $u_N=\int_{N_0}^N f$.

Comment: @zwim Why are we allowed to say the integral on $[n, a_n]$ is exactly $1$ and not just greater than $1$?

Comment: @Newman One can actually "do" this definite integral, and write down a formula for $a_n$ if you so wish.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Right, I'm just curious as to why we are able to say the integral is identically 1 on the subinterval you gave.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Also, why doesn't $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f_n(x)| dx=0$ with the sequence you have suggested? I'm having a little trouble see how this all fits together.

Comment: @Newman Because $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_n=\int_{-\infty}^n \underbrace{f_n}_{=0}+\int_n^{a_n}f_n+\int_{a_n}^{+\infty}\underbrace{f_n}_{=0}=0+1+0=1$ so the limit cannot be $0$.